# How to prove that Rigid rotation is a linear map?

Tags: linear-transformations, rigid-transformation

A rigid rotation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x ,y)$ for all vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that a rigid rotation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in which the origin is fixed is a linear map.

I believe we can have only $48$ such different rigid rotations of the form $(x, y, z)$, $(y, x, z)$, $(-x, y, z)$ etc. but I'm not sure how to reason this. How can I prove this more rigorously?

Comment: What do you mean by 48??

Comment: What definition of 'rotation' are you using in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: $f(x, y, z) = (x, y, z)$ or $f(x, y, z) = (y, z, x)$, i.e. any of the six permutations plus the sign in each. For example, both $f(x, y, z) = (-x, -y, -z)$ and $f(x, y, z) = (x, -y, z) $ are acceptable linear maps which are rigid rotations.

Comment: @john I guess the definition should be "whose determinant is $+1$"?

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi I'd rather consider some of them to be reflections.

Comment: @Vim: but the determinant of what? 'The' matrix of the rotation? If a map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by an $n\times n$ matrix then it is automatically linear. And in any case, determinant $+1$ is too weak to specify a rotation among other linear transformations.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any idea of what a rotation means...I only know that a rigid rotation is defined in this way... plus I know what a linear map means.

Comment: The map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x+1,y,z)$ satisfies the definition of "rigid rotation" as it now appears in the question, but it is not linear by the usual definition since it maps $(0,0,0)$ to something other than $(0,0,0)$.  I would guess you omitted a hypothesis that the origin should be a fixed point. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: There are infinitely many such applications as can be seen by considering for instance $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=(x_1\cos\theta-x_2\sin\theta,x_1\sin\theta+x_2\cos\theta,x_3,\dots,x_n)$.

Comment: @john Determimant is not dependent upon the matrix (which depends on the coordinate system you choose). Given a transformation $f$ in $\Bbb R^n$, we are already enabled to calculate $\det Df$ at every point where $f$ is differentiable. And to my knowledge an isometry is linear if and only if it's an orthogonal transformation, and rotations in the usual sense are orthogonal transformations with positive det.

Comment: Usually mappings $f$ satisfying $\forall x,y,\  d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x ,y)$ are called isometries.  In Euclidean space all isometries are rigid motions. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If that is your definition of rigid rotation, then it is not necessarily linear - translation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by addition of any vector satisfies the conditions to be a rigid rotation, but no translation is linear because it does not preserve the origin.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thankyou, It seems to me that I have incomplete information...

Comment: What does it mean that the origin is a fixed point?

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi $f(0)=0$. Linearity requires a fixed origin. So translations are not linear even if they are isometries.

Comment: Thankyou ... but can you please answer my original question too!

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi Hint: the transformation stated in your problem preserves inner product and fixes origin, so it is an orthogonal (and linear of course) map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ and

- $f(0)=0$ and
- for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ we have $d(x,y) = d(f(x),f(y))$.

We would like to prove that $f(x+y)= f(x)+f(y)$.

We know that $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ and $f(x+y)$ are at the same distance from $0$ and from each other as $x$ and $y$ and $x+y$ from $0$ and from each other.

For any $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ there is a dot-product $x\cdot y\in \mathbb R$, and there is a norm $\|x\|=\sqrt{x\cdot x}$, and we have $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$.

If we can show $\Big(d(f(x+y),f(x)+f(y))\Big)^2=0$, then we've shown $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

The **polarization identity** says
$$
x\cdot y = \frac{\|x+y\|^2 - \|x-y\|^2} 4.
$$
I'll leave the proof of that as an exercise.

---

\begin{align}
& \Big(d(f(x+y),f(x)+f(y))\Big)^2 = \|f(x+y) - f(x) - f(y)\|^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \|f(x+y)\|^2 + \|f(x)\|^2 + \|f(y)\|^2 - 2f(x+y)\cdot f(x) - 2f(x+y)\cdot f(y) + 2f(x)\cdot f(y).
\end{align}

Next I would see if the polarization identity can finish this off.

You also need $f(cx)=cf(x)$ if $c$ is a scalar.  You know that $\|cx\| = |c|\|x\|$.